# Configuring Maven Release Plugin for Git

Tags: git, maven

I am trying to learn how to use the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html). I have made my pom to look like:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:sample/sample-project.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:[fetch=]central[push=]origin</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/sample/sample-project</url>
</scm>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`central` is configured to be the original repo and `origin` is the fork of the repo.

When I try to run `mvn release:prepare` I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project mindmaps-reasoner: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E155007: '/Users/XXXX/IdeaProjects/sample-project/pom.xml' is not a working copy
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Why does it think that this is a svn repo ?

What am I missing to make it work ? In my `~/.scm/git-settings.xml` I have:

```
<git-settings>
    <commitNoVerify>false</commitNoVerify>
</git-settings>
```

**Edit:**

After running `mvn -X release:prepare`, I noticed these lines relating to `svn` being printed:

```
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svnexe:jar:1.9.4:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svn-commons:jar:1.9.4:compile
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svnexe:jar:1.9.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svn-commons:jar:1.9.4
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/fppt/IdeaProjects/mindmaps-reasoner && svn --non-interactive commit --file /var/folders/rj/brkjtdr923l6rgpsyzn_fz280000gn/T/maven-scm-691796700.commit --targets /var/folders/rj/brkjtdr923l6rgpsyzn_fz280000gn/T/maven-scm-9030672937887012174-targets
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] svn: E155007: '/Users/fppt/IdeaProjects/sample-project/pom.xml' is not a working copy
```

Not sure if this provides any more info.

Comment: Well that's weird. What happens when you type the command `mvn scm:validate`?

Comment: @Tunaki Build Success. . . Very confused at this point.

Comment: Would you mind pasting your complete `pom.xml`? The output doesn't make sense, as it's referring to Subversion, and your code (based on your example) is in git. Try running it with `-X` and paste the output.

Comment: @Fido Actually, I wanted to ask: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: So... wait! Is this a git, or Subversion-based project...?! Is it one that's bridging Subversion to Git, or what...?

Comment: @Tanuki. The full results of running `mvn -X release:prepare` http://pastebin.com/GDsyxr4c

Comment: @carlspring It's a git project.

Comment: "Resuming release from phase 'scm-commit-release'" <- I've seen this log. Can you clean your workspace with `mvn release:clean` and try again? Maybe the `release.properties` got messed up and points to a svn repo.

Comment: @Tunaki that did it. Not sure how that happend though. Thanks for the help.